# Does a Bluetooth 5 enabled device support both low energy and classic?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was just curious because on phones it will say in the spec sheet `"Bluetooth: BT4.1, BLE"`

I want to buy a motherboard that supports both Bluetooth 5 Classic and low energy and was just curious if that motherboard would list BLE in the spec sheet? Or is just listing Bluetooth 5 enough?

I just didn't know if the Bluetooth 5 standard consumed low energy and classic and held it under one roof.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the Bluetooth specification is optional, (although there are a lot of depencency rules). Each specification version basically adds a bunch of optional new features, as well as fixing some bugs etc., but hardly ever imposes new requirements to implement new features.

In practice the Bluetooth version of a product just tells the age of the product, although it's often likely that newer products often implement more of the new Bluetooth features.

If you want to know exactly which Bluetooth features a Bluetooth certified product implements, have a look at the certification document for the product at https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/listings.cfm (may require Bluetooth membership to see the detailed list).